Gather Operator Performance Regression
Had some success improving query performance with parallelism, following guidance from here and pgtune. For reference this is analytical workload, not transactional.
First plan, running v16 on EC2 r5b.2xlarge (8vCPU, 64GiB)
https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/4e29dg7b1237af15
This plan was a win. Significant improvement over original query and serial plan and would likely improve further with more CPU cores and parallelism parameter tweaking. Most operators show 5 workers.
Upgrade to r5b.4xlarge instance (16vCPU, 128GiB).
https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/95a31811bbbf0d83
Note the gather operator time has increased from 1931ms to 11776ms. Conversley, operators further down the plan have improved significantly. Worker count 11 for some operators, including the gather.
For the period the gather operator is active, I see only 1 core at 100% via htop.
I was reminded that the majority of EC2 AMD and Intel instances are hyper-threading enabled, including r5b. Will repeat tests with a non-HT instance tomorrow. I've not found any conclusive guidance for HT with postgresql, but it seems logical to try.
Aside from HT, where should I be looking? Is there a limit to postgres parallel processing before performance degrades?
Edit1:
Typical, it's faster today (4s vs 11s) but issue still evident. htop during execution is showing multiple cores active for the entire query, no single core pegged at 100%. Text output for explain, as requested.
https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/1fb5e8cf6391538f#raw
Also, same with settings exactly the same as the first plan. Default apart from max_parallel_gather=8.
https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/c78d4eb85ee1a5bc#raw
Now the gather operator is down to 2s with 5 workers but overall execution time has remained the same because the ColumnarScan of dt_citus.building_base is slower with 5 workers.

Firstly Are you running the PGSql in EC2 or RDS ?
secondly, you are talking on HT and code not been used is it on the Host where the DB Engin resides or your Tool (ETL) to scale up transaction?
Have you tried to optimize the query as I am seing sequence scans?

There seem to be a lot of gratuitous changes between those servers.  For example, jacking up effective_io_concurrency might be reasonable, but why would it be reasonable only for one server and not the other? Run both servers with the same settings, then change on setting at a time until you find the culprit.

@ErwinBrandstetter, updated. Citus extension installed for columnar only.

@jjanes, yes agreed. Followed the reccomendations from webinar as the arguments made for tweaks seemed logical. Yes, will do a methodical sequence of changes to see if any individual change causes a problem. Next stop, a non-HT server.

Running parallel processes incurs considerable overhead and only pays for large enough sets. The final Gather node always runs in a single process on the "leader".
Your settings on the bigger instance (r5b.4xlarge) encourage the Postgres query planner to use many parallel workers:
min_parallel_table_scan_size = 0  -- seems too low to make sense. (default 8 MB)
max_parallel_workers = 80  -- for 16 vCPU with HT, more than 32 is speculative.
parallel_setup_cost = 500  -- why decrease from default 1000?

Might lead to more parallel workers than what's helpful.
While employing that many parallel workers, and since the Gather node seems to be the bottleneck, it might help to disable parallel_leader_participation. That may or may not help other queries, so maybe apply it only locally for your query:
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL parallel_leader_participation = off;
SELECT ...

But it seems the problem is that the Gather node has to wait for one particular worker process lagging behind. Worker 9 (out of 11) takes very long:

Worker Number        9
Actual Startup Time  2s 603ms
Actual Total Time    12s 743ms


All others take ~ 40 ms
It seems like this Worker 9 got stuck doing a lot of work alone, where Postgres had planned to use 11 workers.

Workers planned: 11
Workers launched: 1

Not sure why that happened, maybe max_parallel_workers had been depleted. Which leads me to the initial point. Don't encourage the planner to use too many workers. I think that's better than setting max_parallel_workers to a fantasy number. If more parallel workers are actually used concurrently than your system can support efficiently, overall performance goes down.

I am not to sure how columnar tables best interact with parallelism.
Your last try with 5 workers planned & used is already much better. But you are still comparing apples to oranges. The one before your last test, you still had mostly reasonable settings (besides the ones I disagreed upon above). But the last test runs on default settings out of the box (except for max_parallel_workers_per_gather).
That's inapt for your big database. You previously had random_page_cost = 1, now you run with default random_page_cost = 4. For a dedicated server that can cache most of the DB (and almost all that's used in typical queries), random_page_cost = 1.1 might be best. These all seemed reasonable:
effective_cache_size = '96GB'
effective_io_concurrency = '200'
work_mem = '128MB'

And I would try:
shared_buffers = '40GB'
max_parallel_workers = '32'
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = '16'  -- "no other users"
cpu_tuple_cost = '0.003'
cpu_tuple_cost = '0.0015'

The lack of work_mem shows here:

"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=540527.92..541292.87 rows=76495 width=12)(actual time=6525.294..6554.149 rows=136578 loops=1)"
"        Output: b.id, bb.gfa"
"        Group Key: b.id, bb.gfa"
"        Batches: 5  Memory Usage: 10801kB  Disk Usage: 1728kB"


At least increase work_mem until any mention of "disk" is gone from the EXPLAIN ANALYZE output.
There might also be potential with better index and/or rewriting the query.
Either way, this has now devolved from answering a question into consultant work.

Thanks Erwin. Will update with text output later, when I have the 16 vCPU back. The parallel settings were from the linked webinar. This server is dedicated to my testing, no other users, hence using the higher settings.
Your observation of worker 9 mirrors what I could see via htop, 100% cpu on 1 core only. Comments have helped me understand plan details for postgres also, thank you.

So it's actually Worker 9 in the aggregate node #4. It's the only worker that processes the rows, all the others process zero.

Thanks again. As mentioned, the wild settings were from the swarm64 guy. Will try your suggestions and report back.
